# Windows phone 7 - Bing maps return error :- The remote server returned an error: NotFound

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, bing-maps

In my app I have to use bing map.

So that I create a new Xaml and drag and drop the map control.

I did not do any other functions in this xaml.

I just click one button and navigate to this map page.

But after 5 to 10 sec I receiving error message:- **The remote server returned an error: NotFound**. But I din not send any request to my server.

I don't know why this error happening. If I try with new example I can do all the map functions.

But I can not include in my Main project.

Please let me know what is the exact problem.

The error message is:-

```
    System.Net.WebException was unhandled
  Message=The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state)
       at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at SharpGIS.GZipHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps.Map.LogResponse(IAsyncResult result)
       at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClassa.<InvokeGetResponseCallback>b__8(Object state2)
       at System.Threading.ThreadPool.WorkItem.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadPool.WorkItem.doWork(Object o)
       at System.Threading.Timer.ring()
  InnerException: System.Net.WebException
       Message=The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
       StackTrace:
            at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
            at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClass2.<EndGetResponse>b__1(Object sendState)
            at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<BeginOnUI>b__0(Object sendState)
            at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(RuntimeMethodInfo rtmi, Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isBinderDefault, Assembly caller, Boolean verifyAccess, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
            at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
            at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
            at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeOne(Object[] args)
            at System.MulticastDelegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
            at System.Delegate.DynamicInvoke(Object[] args)
            at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.<>c__DisplayClass4.<FastInvoke>b__3()
            at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(RuntimeMethodInfo rtmi, Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isBinderDefault, Assembly caller, Boolean verifyAccess, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
            at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
            at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
            at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeOne(Object[] args)
            at System.MulticastDelegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
            at System.Delegate.DynamicInvoke(Object[] args)
            at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
            at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Dispatch(DispatcherPriority priority)
            at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.OnInvoke(Object context)
            at System.Windows.Hosting.CallbackCookie.Invoke(Object[] args)
            at System.Windows.Hosting.DelegateWrapper.InternalInvoke(Object[] args)
            at System.Windows.RuntimeHost.ManagedHost.InvokeDelegate(IntPtr pHandle, Int32 nParamCount, ScriptParam[] pParams, ScriptParam& pResult)
```

Comment: error straight a way says that server is not available

Comment: But server is available. I can do other functions in my app.

Comment: [please check this sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Bing-Maps-950491b9)

Comment: Hi @ vits.. Yes. Already I use this sample. When I create new project I can implement this example. But when I try to include my main project I receiving error..